# SDL2 free null pointer

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

Is it safe to do this:

```
SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
```

Or do I have to do this:

```
if(window != NULL)
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
}
```

I know that it is safe to free a null pointer using free(void*) in stdlib.h, but I want to know if the same goes for SDL functions

Comment: Reading the docs could be enlighting...

Comment: What kind of design are you using where you don't know if a window instance is NULL or not:(

Comment: If you free something that is nulled you won't get an exception. But the former is way more clearer and nicer code.

Comment: @CamelToe OP is not asking what `free` does.

Comment: @marom it does not say anything I think...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation doesn't say either way](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyWindow?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29), but I can see from the v2.0.3 source code that `SDL_DestroyWindow` does have protection against a null pointer input.

That being said, it's undocumented and I can't even promise how reliable this `CHECK_WINDOW_MAGIC` macro is across all build modes, so you should take the `if` statement approach.

Besides, if you can have a NULL window then I question your design.

Comment: The FUD over null pointers is just out of control now.  Who cares?   If a null ptr is dereferenced, the app blows up and it gets fixed.  FFS, there are a lot more pernicious, insidious bugs in most apps than null pointers.   IMHO, there should not be any protection and the thing should except violently so that the developer has to fix the root cause.

Comment: Is it the same for all SDL_Destroy... functions?

Comment: @MartinJames: That's what I said in my final paragraph.

Comment: @ErikW: Examine the source like I did and find out!